# What does nginx's $time_local logging variable mean, specifically?

Tags: nginx

I'm reading some nginx logs for some rather long-lasting requests (up to 10 seconds). In the log format, we're using the `$time_local` variable to record the time. But does this mean the time when the request *started* or when it *finished*? For a long-running request, these are quite distinct times, and I can't find anything in the [ngx_http_log_module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) to explain this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `$time_local` variable contains the time when the log entry is written.

when the HTTP request header is read, nginx does a lookup of the associated virtual server configuration. If the virtual server is found, the request goes through six phases:

- server rewrite phase
- location phase
- location rewrite phase (which can bring the request back to the previous phase)
- access control phase
- try_files phase
- log phase

Since the log phase is the last one, `$time_local` variable is much more colse to the end of the request than it's start.

Comment: thanks.. can you show me where I could have found this in the documentation?

Comment: http://www.nginx.com/docs.html
The information is on the link "The Architecture of Open Source Applications Volume II" which is a good reference book.

Comment: Looks like they've changed the URL. It's now at https://nginx.org/en/docs/ with the reference book at http://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html.

Comment: None of those links, nor the [doc page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) explains `time_local` specifically.

Comment: NB this differs from Apache, which uses the start time in its default log https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html