# How to log the start time of a request in Nginx

Tags: nginx

As stated in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/438891/186428), the $time_local variable in access log of Nginx means the **end time** of a request (or close to).

Then, is there some way to log the **start time** of a request in Nginx access log?

I've googled around but just can't find any references to achive this. Come on! Isn't this a very simple function for a web server? Do not tell me to subtract the $request_time from the $time_local ...

Comment: Haproxy has this feature ('option logasap') but nginx doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I think it deserves an update, for  `nginx>1.2.5` (as of July 2017 nginx stable is `1.13`) this is now trivial

In the log use

```
start_time="$msec"
```

Or to add a header:

```
add_header X-Request-Start $msec
```

or for a proxy

```
proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec
```

Comment: The documentation says $msec is "time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution **at the time of the log write**", and AFAIU access logs are written when the request ends.

Comment: I think you're confusing $msec in log messages with a variable of the same name added to headers. One think is certain - in this context it's not the time logs are written, as you say logs are written at the end of requests and this header is added before requests are proxied. Nginx would have to be able to predict the future to know when a request will end before it's proxied.

Comment: But that's for the add_header/proxy_set_header alternatives, isn't it?  I'm still confused about the first suggested alternative "in the log use `start_time="$msec"`".

Comment: Yes, unless there's a way to write logs at the beginning rather than end of requests

Comment: So. I've actually tried this now. The general idea "you have to set the start time manually somehow" is sound, but using headers did not work for me. What did work is using variables: In your location (or similar) put `set $request_start $msec;`; then you can use `$request_start` in your `log_format`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a patch for nginx (https://gist.github.com/rkbodenner/318681#comment-610856) that exposes request start time as a variable.

I think it could be useful in your case.

Comment: Well, though the patch is a little bit too difficult for us newbie to understand and apply, it indicates that there's no such built-in feature in Nginx. Thx any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `$msec` and `$request_time` to the log and use `$msec` - `$request_time` as the start time when parsing.